# List comprehension: retrieve valid strings if not contained in a list of substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to check if a list of filenames can be copied and I check this against a list of fobidden substrings.

Here is what I have:

```
exclude = ['ex','xe']
files = ['include', 'exclude']
```

And this is what I expect:

```
['include']
```

I already got it working with a list comprehension, like this:

```
[a[0] for a in [(f, any([e in f for e in exclude])) for f in files] if not a[1]]
```

Where I create a tuple `(f, any([e in f for e in exclude]))` checking if there is any correspondence on the filename to the excluding substrings.
I do this for every file in the list of files `for f in files` and include only those that don't exist on the excluding substrings `if not a[1]`.

Is there a better way to this? A more pythonic one?
Because I'm looping through the file list 2 times and I'm guessing there is a way to this in one go!

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really understand your logic. Looks like you're building tuples with boolean values, then filter the `False` values out.

It seems to me that this also works and is simpler:

```
exclude = ['ex','xe']
files = ['include', 'exclude']

print([x for x in files if not any(e in x for e in exclude)])
```

it loops through `files`, and for each file, checks that no `exclude` member is included in it.

Note that you don't have to build an actual list in `any`. Omit the square brackets, let `any` perform a lazy evaluation, it's faster.

Comment: this is what I was looking for! I knew there was a better way but was stuck on that. Thank you!

Comment: Also didn't know about the lazy evaluation. Thanks for that note. Always learning!

Answer (score 0):

This will only loop through the file list one time:

```
[file for file in files if not any(item in file for item in exclude)]
```

It does loop through the exclude list once for every item in the file list so if you have a long exclude list the performance might take a hit.

Comment: Check out the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) functions.  They short-circuit, meaning they don't go through the whole input iterable if  they already "know" whether or not they succeeded.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Plus they're clearer (which I find more important).

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Good point, updated to include an any generator, which it turns out is the same as the accepted answer